# Typescript generics is rejected when specifying `keyof?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a generic method which is from  the RXJS library  (*here simplified*)  :

```
function Subject<T>(t: T):T {
    return t;
}
```

I also have an interface which declares my app values. (*keys can be added*)

```
interface IState { 
    key1: number;
    key2: string;
}
```

And finally I have a `Store` which applies to the `IState` interface with actual values, via the  generic function wrapper ( *the generic function is an alias to the `RXJS` subject*)

```
let Store  : IState=  Subject<IState>({  
    key1: void 0,
    key2: void 0,

})
```

Ok so lets add 2 method for getting  & setting from store :

Setting to store :

```
 function set<T>(name: keyof IState, statePart: T) {
        Store={
            ...Store,
            [name]: statePart 
        };
```

Usage : `set<string>("key1", "3");`

This function works fine and allows me to *only use valid keys which belongs to `IState`*. No errors here.

But looking at the `Select` method :

(invocation should be like: )

```
let myVal:number = select<number>("key1");
```

Here is the method :

```
function select<T>(k: keyof IState): T { 
    return <T>Store[k];  // <-- error here
}
```

> Type 'string | number' cannot be converted to type 'T'.   Type
>   'number' is not comparable to type 'T'.

**Question:**

Why is that ?  If I remove the `keyof`  :

```
function select<T>(k): T { 
    return <T>Store[k];
}
```

Then it does compile , but it's not making any sense , `Store` is type of `Istate` and `Istate` contains keys of `Istate`

Why does it work without `keyof` and how can I fix my code so that `select` method will force to select only  keys of `Istate` ?

[**ONLINE DEMO**](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=function%20Subject%3CT%3E(t%3A%20T)%3AT%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20t%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20IState%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20key1%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20key2%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20Store%20%20%3A%20IState%3D%20%20Subject%3CIState%3E(%7B%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20key1%3A%20void%200%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20key2%3A%20void%200%2C%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%7D)%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20select%3CT%3E(k%3A%20keyof%20IState)%3A%20T%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%3CT%3EStore%5Bk%5D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20function%20set%3CT%3E(name%3A%20keyof%20IState%2C%20statePart%3A%20T)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Store%3D%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20...Store%2C%20%5Bname%5D%3A%20statePart%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Aconsole.log(Store)%3B%0D%0Aset%3Cstring%3E(%22key1%22%2C%20%223%22)%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(Store)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20myVal%3Anumber%20%3D%20select%3Cnumber%3E(%22key1%22)%3B%0D%0A)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `k` can be any key of `IState`  so there is no way to make sure that `Store[k]` is compatible with `T`. I  would change the generic parameter to be the key, and type the result in relation to the field type:

```
function select<K extends keyof IState>(k: K): IState[K] { 
    return Store[k];
}
let myVal  = select("key1"); // myval is number
```

Also `set` can be improved to not have explicit generic parameters, and to ensure the value passed to `set` is compatible with the field type:

```
function set<K extends keyof IState>(name: K, statePart: IState[K]) {
    Store={
        ...Store,
        [name]: statePart 
    }
}

set("key1", 3);
```

**Edit**

As mentioned in the comments, you can see the actual inferred types if you hover over the call (at least in vscode):

[image]

If you want to keep the explicit type parameters, although I do not recommend this as you can easily mismatch the field type and the call type you can use a type assertion through `any`:

```
function select3<T>(k: keyof IState): T { 
    return Store[k] as any;
}
```

Comment: Thanks — But now , as a programmer , I find it hard to see what the actual type as  opposed to the previous case where I used to see it as `select<string>(..).... now i know and expect it to be a string...`.

Comment: @RoyiNamir yes, but in your case you are actually not type safe, since for `set` for example you can accidentally specify the wrong type (as you actually do in the question `key1` is number but you pass a `string` to `set`. If you hover in your IDE over the call you will see the actual types inferred for the call. There is a solution to make your code work but it involves type assertions and is not type safe. I will add it to the answer for completeness.

Comment: Thanks Titian - I didn't even notice that It wasn't typesafed in my example ;)

Comment: @RoyiNamir neither did I until I typed the function, such errors are very easy to make, best let the compiler infer as much as possible and give errors when it detects things are not compatible

Comment: BTW why was the compiler happy with `function select<T>(k): T { 
    return <T>Store[k];
}` ? , worst it allowed me this `select<number>("key2")` //where key2 is a string`

Comment: You can type assert through `any` as i updated in the answer, but type assertion will not let you assert directly between two unrelated types, see double assertion here : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/type-assertion.html

Comment: Btw I've searched for the documentation about the return type such ad Istate[k] , but i didnt find. Under what category should i search?

Comment: @RoyiNamir it's called a type query http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html